# Proper re-tagging with "windows" and "linux" tags, or other OS-specific tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I think I am not alone in experiencing a dislike for having to read a question I think is for linux, only to find out that someone is running apache on windows-7 or windows95 or 3.1 or cp/m or whatever. Sometimes you have to read quite a bit before this is clear and so retagging saves someone else time.  Sometimes it is not clear what O/S is involved until you answer and the person says, oh, I meant windows.

Is it OK to retag questions that are O/S specific with the O/S tag, or is the tag only meant for issues specifically about that O/S?

Maybe this just isn't clear and there is not a clean distinction.

What is current practice?

Answer (score 3):

It's especially important on SF and SU to tag the OS involved, since most of those types of problems are OS specific.

On SO it's less of a problem, but when it's important to the question, then the OS should be tagged.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with [Lance Roberts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/13295/lance-roberts), but I'd add that if the OS is only incidental to the problem, then do not include it in a tag.

Comment: agree, sometimes the OS isn't critical to the problem.  in the hypothetical Apache-on-win7 question, if the problem/answer has only to do with what's in the Apache configuration files, no *[win7]* tag is needed.

Answer (score 1):

If a question is specifically about how to do something in a given environment, then I think it's totally appropriate to tag the question with that environment.