# Tag to Use for a Windows-specific App-config Question

Tags: discussion, tags, asking-questions

I am running Sublime Text 3 on Windows (7 Pro x64) and asked a [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22952568/1810429) about configuring it.  It seems to me that not tagging my question to convey that it specifically relates to Sublime Text 3 on Windows could waste my and others' time, but I am not sure what tag to use.

I considered tagging my question with [windows], but the tag's [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/windows/info)'s excerpt says:

> If your question has nothing to do with Windows APIs or Windows-specific behaviour then do not use this tag, even if you are running on Windows.

Hmmm, I think my question may come down to Windows-specific Sublime Text 3 behavior (particularly since the default settings file is supposed to be under `C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming`), but I am not really sure.

I also searched MSO for clear guidance how I should tag my question to reflect its (expected) Windows-specificity...but did not find any in the search results I read.

How should I tag a question to reflect that it specifically relates to a multi-platform tool running on Windows?

Comment: I noticed [Proper re-tagging with "windows" and "linux" tags, or other OS-specific tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40532/219145) in the list of related questions to this right of this one.  It provides some of the perspective I wanted in posting this question, but it ultimately lands on judging the OS-relatedness of the question at hand.  Some informed perspective on my specific situation in that respect still interests me.

Comment: I think just use [tag:sublimetext3] without [tag:windows]. Then, mention that it is Windows-specific only in the first place on the body. But I'm not sure myself.

Comment: @AndrewT: Thanks for sharing your perspective: I posted [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22952568/1810429) on SO and for now simply noted in it that I am running Sublime Text 3 on Windows 7 Pro x64.